# Break the loop/promise and return from function

Tags: javascript, promise, protractor

I have following code snippet.

```
this.clickButtonText = function (buttonText, attempts, defer) {
    var me = this;
    if (attempts == null) {
        attempts = 3;
    }
    if (defer == null) {
        defer = protractor.promise.defer();
    }

    browser.driver.findElements(by.tagName('button')).then(function (buttons) {
        buttons.forEach(function (button) {
            button.getText().then(
                function (text) {
                    console.log('button_loop:' + text);
                    if (text == buttonText) {
                        defer.fulfill(button.click());
                        console.log('RESOLVED!');
                        return defer.promise;
                    }
                },
                function (err) {
                    console.log("ERROR::" + err);
                    if (attempts > 0) {
                        return me.clickButtonText(buttonText, attempts - 1, defer);
                    } else {
                        throw err;
                    }
                }
            );
        });
    });

    return defer.promise;
};
```

From time to time my code reaches *'ERROR::StaleElementReferenceError: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document'* line so I need to try again and invoke my function with **"attempt - 1"** parameter. That is expected behaviour.
But once it reaches **"RESOLVED!"** line it keeps iterating so I see smth like this:

```
button_loop:wrong_label_1
button_loop:CORRECT_LABEL
RESOLVED!
button_loop:wrong_label_2
button_loop:wrong_label_3
button_loop:wrong_label_4
```

**The question is:** how to break the loop/promise and return from function after *console.log('RESOLVED!');* line?

Comment: have you tried using `.done` callbacks?

Comment: no, but seems checking whether my shared defer is resolved works for me. Will wait for more elegant answer and if not will provide my own

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to stop or break a forEach() loop other than by throwing an exception. If you need such behavior, the forEach() method is the wrong tool, use a plain loop instead.

SOURCE: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: That's not _forEach_ but _button.getText()_ keeps executing. So I need to break the Protractor's flow

Answer (score 0):

Out of curiosity what are you trying to accomplish? To me it seems like you want to click a button based on it's text so you are iterating through all buttons on the page limited by an attempt number until you find a match for the text.

It also looks like you are using protractor on a non-angular page it would be easier if you used `browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;` in your spec files or the onPrepare block in the `conf.js` file so you could still leverage the protractor API which has two element locators that easily achieve this.

```
this.clickButtonText = function(buttonText) {
    return element.all(by.cssContainingText('button',buttonText)).get(0).click();
};
```

**OR**

```
this.clickButtonText = function(buttonText) {
    return element.all(by.buttonText(buttonText)).get(0).click();
};
```

If there is another reason for wanting to loop through the buttons I could write up a more complex explanation that uses [bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html) to loop through the elements. It is a very useful library for resolving promises.

Answer (score 0):

You are making it harder on yourself by creating an extra deferred object. You can use the promises themselves to retry the action if the click fails.

```
var clickOrRetry = function(element, attempts) {
    attempts = attempts === undefined ? 3 : attempts;
    return element.click().then(function() {}, function(err) {
        if (attempts > 0) {
            return clickOrRetry(element, attempts - 1);
        } else {
            throw new Error('I failed to click it -- ' + err);
        }
    });
};

return browser.driver.findElements(by.tagName('button')).then(function(buttons) {
    return buttons.forEach(function(button) {
        return clickOrRetry(button);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to build (at each "try") a promise chain that continues on failure but skips to the end on success. Such a chain would be of the general form ...

```
return initialPromise.catch(...).catch(...).catch(...)...;
```

... and is simple to construct programmatically using the javascript Array method `.reduce()`.

In practice, the code will be made bulky by :

- the need to call the async `button.getText()` then perform the associated test for matching text,
- the need to orchestrate 3 tries,

but still not too unwieldy.

As far as I can tell, you want something like this :

```
this.clickButtonText = function (buttonText, attempts) {
    var me = this;
    if(attempts === undefined) {
        attempts = 3;
    }
    return browser.driver.findElements(by.tagName('button')).then(function(buttons) {
        return buttons.reduce(function(promise, button) {
            return promise.catch(function(error) {
                return button.getText().then(function(text) {
                    if(text === buttonText) {
                        return button.click(); // if/when this happens, the rest of the catch chain (including its terminal catch) will be bypassed, and whatever is returned by `button.click()` will be delivered.
                    } else {
                        throw error; //rethrow the "no match" error
                    }
                });
            });
        }, Promise.reject(new Error('no match'))).catch(function(err) {
            if (attempts > 0) {
                return me.clickButtonText(buttonText, attempts - 1); // retry
            } else {
                throw err; //rethrow whatever error brought you to this catch; probably a "no match" but potentially an error thrown by `button.getText()`.
            }
        });
    });
};
```

Notes :

- With this approach, there's no need to pass in a deferred object. In fact, whatever approach you adopt, that's bad practice anyway. Deferreds are seldom necessary, and even more seldom need to be passed around.
- I moved the terminal `catch(... retry ...)` block to be a final catch, after the catch chain built by reduce. That makes more sense than an `button.getText().then(onSucccess, onError)` structure, which would cause a retry at the first failure to match buttonText; that seems wrong to me.
- You could move the terminal catch even further down such that an error thrown by `browser.driver.findElements()` would be caught (for retry), though that is probably overkill. If `browser.driver.findElements()` fails once, it will probably fail again.
- the "retry" strategy could be alternatively achieved by 3x concatenatation of the catch chain built by the `.reduce()` process. But you would see a larger memory spike.
- I omitted the various console.log()s for clarity but they should be quite simple to reinject.